# How can I change CP language in Craft 3 after installation?

Tags: craft3

I saw how I can change system language (CP) after installation in Craft 2, but I can't find how to do it in Craft 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language of CP depends on user. Therefore, you have to set Users -> admin -> Preferences and set prefered language.

Comment: Just a heads up. On a Solo distribution of Craft CMS, you don't have the 'Users' menu item. Then you find the language setting by clicking your site name/user name on the top of the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings > sites, there you can change it.

Comment: It was "done" before my question, but Control Panel stills English.